# Why does parallel doesn't work using '{}' but '--'?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Following the man pages and other examples the following should work:

```
$ find  *.gz | parallel zgrep pattern {}
```

but it results in:

```
/bin/zgrep: line 161: 1: missing pattern; try `/bin/zgrep --help' for help
/bin/bash: pattern: command not found
/bin/bash: {}: command not found
```

while substituting the '{}' with '--' works fine:

```
$ find  *.gz | parallel zgrep pattern  --
```

Why is this? 
(using GNU parallel 20121122 and GNU parallel 20130922)

Comment: Don't you get: `parallel: Warning: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.
parallel: Warning: --tollef is obsolete and will be retired 20140222.
parallel: Warning: See: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2013-02/msg00018.html`

Comment: I don't get this message when invoking the man page examples but when I invoke _parallel --version_ (which by coincidence I did at some point).Anyway, great tool, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by coincidence:
one has to use `parallel --gnu` to make the examples of the man pages work. Dooh!